What does that horizontal line in Audio Spectrum do?
What does that horizontal line a bit below 30khz do? Is is suppose to be there? What is it called?


This is your recording! You would be the one who is most likely to know. What did you record there, with which recording setup? Note that this isn't what I'd call "actual audio" anyways, human hearing doesn't really extend above 20 to 22 kHz, so having things above indicates that "traditional audio equipment" wisdom isn't applied here, as ultrasonic components are more of a liability than a boon for reproduction. So, you have to tell us what this recording shows!

(96 kHz sampling rate recording might make sense in a studio environment, where there might be advantages of being able to use less sharp low-pass filters. Soon as you save it to a disk, I'd go with "it's too high")

This is acually the flac music I bought from hdtracks

could it be some sort of artifacts? Since it's a music, it shouldn't have this kind of "line" right?

If this is music, why do you care about something at 30 kHz? nobody during production would have cared, either, because they're producing music for humans, not dogs nor bats. 30 kHz is solidly out of human hearing range.

@MarcusMüller: I've seen a case (from the Billboard top 100, no less) with a massive peak above 20 kHz which was a serious clipping risk for any postprocessing where you would least expect it.

@Hilmar ooooops! OK, but the line in case here seems to be at -85 dBFS, if I interpret the dB scala that way, so, that risk is manageable. But yeah, one more reason to make sure your audio doesn't reach into the ultrasonic.

Could just be a constant tone in the recording circuitry, ADC, etc.  The stuff I design frequently has these and it's difficult to completely eliminate them.

I acually don't really care what that line is, I just want to know if it's a artifact or not. Cause artifact normally means this is resampled(which is bad)

@james I think we can both ascribe "an artefact is usually due to resampling" AND "resampling is bad" to the land of myths.

@james: Of course it's sampled and most likely up-sampled.  The original recoding was made in 1979 and the likelihood of any significant energy at 30 kHz in  a 1979 recording is indeed very, very small. sorry, but selling tracks from this era as 96kHz or 192 kHz seems disingenuous to me. Your much more likely to pick some artifacts than preserve anything meaningful from the original recording.


This is acually the flac music I bought from hdtracks

Could be a few different things:

Unintentional production artifact. That could have sneaked in during recording, production and/or mastering. This things do happen and in one extreme case, I tracked it down to a specific keyboard sample that was used in that song. Since its so uniform in your case it could be one of the drum samples.
Could be intentional, maybe watermarking. This could be a way to sneak a copyright notice or a unique identifier into the recording that helps the label to track down the source if the recording shows up where it shouldn't (yes, they are excessively paranoid that way).
Could be real. Maybe it's a percussion instrument or cymbal that has a strong resonance at 29 kHz (which is typically not audible, so no one cares).
Could be an up sampling artifact. Many HD tracks (especially older ones) start their life at 44.1kHz or 48 kHz and than are simply up sampled to create the so-called "HD" version.

Could be something complete different. Can you share the details of the track?

re: 2. well, a watermark that gets filtered out whenever the uncompressed track is re-encoded for transport, nor would make it onto a CD… is not that useful?

HD tracks are considerably more expensive than CD quality tracks, so they may warrant extra protection. 44.kHz/16 bit tracks are remarkably difficult to buy these days since CD themselves are mostly extinct. A small handful of services offer CD quality streaming but these have their own security arrangements with the labels. At least  one label did indeed watermark content in  ways that survived codecs can postprocessing but also audibly degraded the content. That was a subject of spirted discussion :-)

Huh, I can very well imagine the spirited discussion that happened there!

This is "High Way To Hell" from ac/dc

are you sure that could be a sampling artifact? Cause the spectrum seems to cover a really wide range, if it's resampled, then there should be a distinctive line where frequnency stopped at the same height right?

@james you might implement a resampler that way, yes, but you don't have to – since at the point of resampling an old record for a new sampling rate, you already know that your upsampling filtering doesn't have to be very sharp at all – the listener still can't hear things above 20 kHz, so you go for the flatter passband at same delay / phase distortion and use a more relaxed resampling filter. After all, for playback, the reproduction system will get rid of impossible-to-reproduce-physically signal, anyways.

(there's exceptions to that, and Hilmar mentions one of these in the comments under your question – but that example failure doesn't apply to your signal – both the tone at ~ 30 kHz and the higher-frequency wideband signals are a solid amount weaker than your audible spectrum. Note that having more this much more than the necessary sample rate for audible frequencies outside of a studio processing chain has no upsides, but potentially downsides; see my first link in the comments under your question. If you need good reproduction of an already mastered, mixed and produced song,

get a 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz version; resampling from the audio 96 or 192 kHz to 48 kHz is not "bad"; it just literally removes completely since physically irrelevant content, and removes potential for things that can mess up your acoustic reproduction of the song.)
